# Are there any online wallets available for Litecoin?

Tags: e-wallet, litecoin

Are there any litecoin wallets available on the internet right now? I have a mac and the mac version software is very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are! Check the [Litecoin Wiki](http://litecoin.info/Main_Page) for more information, and a list of services.

Answer (score 1):

We have just released http://www.coinwallet.co which supports Litecoin.

Answer (score 1):

[Harborly](http://harbor.ly) is a US based litecoin wallet that also allows you to buy and sell with your bank account.

Answer (score 0):

According to the current [Wallet service overview](https://litecoin.info/Service_directory#Wallet_services) of the [Litecoin-Wiki](https://litecoin.info) there are six online wallet-services (copied from there):

- [liteaddress.org](http://liteaddress.org/) - Litecoin address generation tools
- [reddit ALTcointip bot](http://www.reddit.com/r/ALTcointip/wiki/index) - give and receive Litecoin tips from reddit users
- [Coinkite](https://www.coinkite.com/) - Coinkite is a web wallet with merchant services, Point-of-Sale terminals and debit cards. Sign up here
- [CoinWallet.co](https://www.coinwallet.co/) - Online wallet
- [Harborly](http://harbor.ly/) - Online wallet that can be linked with any US bank account
- [HolyTransaction](https://holytransaction.com/) - Online wallet, multi-currency support