# Getting an online Litecoin wallet

Tags: wallet, litecoin

I want a litecoin wallet to store the litecoins that I am going to buy with my bank account. I wanted to use ltc-wallet.com but when I try to go the site, it doesn't load. Also, when I went to sign up for btc-e I find [many](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=217697.0), [many](https://www.bitcoinforum.com/bitcoin-exchange/btc-e-is-a-scam-with-photo-proof/), [MANY](https://forum.litecoin.net/index.php?topic=3305.0) sites that say that Btc-e is a scam. Finally I found coinbase.com ...which also came with a plethora of [horror stories](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=165350.0). Is there a LEGITIMATE site that I could use in order to store my litecoins?

Comment: cryptsy.com seems legit, they are US-based at least.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any online wallets available for Litecoin?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9021/are-there-any-online-wallets-available-for-litecoin)

Answer (score 1):

It's been reported that ltc wallet is DOWN and people have been scammed. Unfortunately there isn't a reputable online ltc wallet at the moment that I'd trust with a 10 foot pole. The ones that have come are just as quickly gone run by fly by night scammers. You're best off encrypting your wallet with a very secure password and making multiple copies of your wallet file that you store in remote, secure locations if you want to protect yourself from loss should your drive ever die on you.

The other option would be to start an account at an exchange that trades in litecoin and use it as your online wallet. Just be sure to use a well established exchange, of which I'm only aware of btc-e.com

Comment: should i buy litecoins from btc-e?

Comment: They're really the only ltc exchange I would trust ATM. They've been around the longest and are established.

Comment: @Coder404 but you said in your post that btc.e is a scam. Have you changed your mind and trust them now?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Harborly](http://harbor.ly/) they allow you to store litecoins in an online wallet and buy/sell litecoins with a US bank account.

Answer (score 0):

Another virtual currency exchange you can use to keep your litecoins in is [Vircurex](https://vircurex.com/).

I can't vouch for the reliability and trustworthiness of Vircurex, but I've experimented with it a couple of times and not lost any coins so far.

But I would advise to store them in a cold off-line wallet (paper or digital storage) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can get litecoin wallet straight on any crypto exchange.

http://btc-e.com

http://vircurex.com

http://litecoinglobal.com

http://bter.com

https://coinex.pw

http://justcoin.com

http://www.converterhub.com

mtgox made advertisement that namecoin and litecoin [coming soon](https://www.mtgox.com/press_release_20130805.html).

> LiteCoin Update
>
> We hate to apologize yet again for the delay in
>   implementing Litecoin, but the fact of the matter is that it depends
>   on a variety of factors, including completing all of the above before
>   we launch. We're looking forward to the rollout, but at this point are
>   reluctant to speculate on when. We are sorry to keep Litecoin
>   enthusiasts hanging.

Answer (score 0):

Most online wallets are scammers.

I just tried one of them, and they stole my LTC.

It's much better to use your own Smart Phone or PC as a wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Here are ways I store Litecoin online and their (referral) links after I get BTC from Coinbase and then sent it to...

Cryptsy (https://www.cryptsy.com/users/register?refid=64025): buggy at times (rare overbuy and oversell issues (the former causing a negative balance) and some claim it "deletes" their coins but I've only had the negative balance problem once (just sold back the coins when they went up)  and its a quite slow/laggy but has tons of alt coins to play with and charts for each (google: coinmarketcap) is a good way to see what's hot but it changes all the time so sometimes its on its way back down after you buy some LOL). Hopefully they'll get more "server power" soon with additional hardware to speed things up and fix the bugs in the near future if not already); USD as well as Escrow are future features but you can do LTC/BTC and LTC has its own markets too (altcoin/LTC; they sometimes have less action than BTC market though even when there's an altcoin they have in common IMO).

BTC-e: good in conjunction with Bitcoinwisdom (google it) for looking at exchange rates of LTC/USD and LTC/BTC (hover your mouse over markets and select a BTC-e exchange you like (I move BTC to it because it only accepts USD from Russian Paypal-like services some of which only provide services to non-US residents (Perfect Money and OKpay of the ones I tried) or want you to verify your account by filling out snail mail from Russia (Liqpay, the intermediary service for Payeer). No thanks to that.). The chat feature (troll box) is fun to watch but you need $100 or more net worth to post and you can get banned from the troll box for minutes, hours, or even days depending on the whims of the wavers of the banhammer! LOL

LTC4YOU: not a wallet but a time-wasting game b/c you only get about 0.000005 LTC (5 uLTC or micro LTC) per hour (used to be six times that but varies based on current price and number of referrals you get) but it's free so that's better than nothing (probably best to deposit it to an offline LTC wallet like Litecoin-Qt (b/c LTC deposit addresses on exchanges may change over time maybe?) and make sure to change the payout address in the Accounts tab to the offline one because it made mine into something random (it was said to be your own private address for this site) after I signed up so when I requested my payout it directed to who-knows-where (I thought it was suspicious but after e-mailing the staff, they were more than willing to help and fixed it to what I requested it to be). Also know that the withdrawal fee as of wallet version 0.8.6.1 is lower than before as 0.001 LTC. As for pros, it's fun to see the numbers go around and around, the chance at the jackpot (0.001 LTC or more to 30 people at random each day), and added benefits (increased hourly winnings) with referring people like this... http://ltc4you.com/?r=1956

Happy Crypcoining!

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but none of the services you introduce seem to actually be online wallets.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the newly launched https://www.coinwallet.co for Litecoin

Comment: Why the down vote??

Answer (score -1):

I use cryptsy.com for most altcoins. It's secure and has low withdrawal fees.

Comment: It is, however, not a wallet-service but an exchange, i.e. it might be lacking features inherent to wallet-services such as tagging recipient addresses etc. while transactions are much more expensive. Is that the case?